# Python Tkinter Scrollbar too small cannot be seen?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Can anyone explain why the scrollbar is not working in my python code?

See `#add_scroll_bar` section. I wish the scrollbar locate next to the treeview widget. Hence, the scrollbar is only scrolling through the content but not the tkinter frame.

See python code below

```
import requests
import json 
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# open tkinter interface
root =tk.Tk()

#change GUID interface
length=600
width=450

root.geometry(str(length)+'x'+str(width))
root.title('Helium Earning Tracker')

#label
x1=50
y1=30

tk.Label(root,text='Helium Miner Address').place(x=x1,y=y1,anchor='w')
tk.Label(root,text='Blocks').place(x=x1,y=(y1*2)+20,anchor='w')
tk.Label(root,text='Result').place(x=x1,y=(y1*4)+20,anchor='w')

columns=['Date','HNT Amount','HNT Price','Daily Earning']

#add data-box
tvw=ttk.Treeview(root,columns=columns,show='headings')
tvw.place(x=x1,y=(y1*9)+20,anchor='w')

for c1 in range(len(columns)):
    tvw.heading(columns[c1],text=str(columns[c1]))
    tvw.column(columns[c1],width=len(columns[c1])*14)

contacts = []
for n in range(1, 100):
    contacts.append((f'first {n}', f'last {n}', f'email{n}@example.com'))

# add data to the treeview
for contact in contacts:
    tvw.insert('', tk.END, values=contact)

#add_scroll_bar
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root,orient='vertical',command=tvw.yview)
tvw.configure(yscroll=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side= 'left',fill='y')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1st do not post a screen shot of code. Please post a testable example preferable as short as possible to illustrate the issue. I will say the fact that you are using place instead of grid() or pack() is going to be your main problem here.

`place()` should be used for specific needs an in 99% of most things you do in tkinter you will need to use `grid()` or `pack()`. Me personally I use `grid()` for just about everything. With pack or grid you can get your scroll bar to properly expand.

Comment: The scrollbar is filling all the vertical space of the root window and it is *not small*.  It works as expected since you configure `command=tvw.yview`.